# VirtualPathProvider is not being called for a file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I got a `VirtualPathProvider` which I register with `HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new MyVirtualPathProvider())` in global.asax.

The `FileExists` method is called for my `screen.js` and returns `true`, but the `GetFile` method is never called. Why do it check for the file but do not try to use it?

How can I fix it?

Comment: You may want to provide more code and context.  Think about asking a mechanic.  "I have gas in my car, and when I press the gas pedal the engine runs but I don't go anywhere.  How do I fix it?"

Comment: MVC usually do something like this: `if (provider.FileExists(uri)) resource = provider.GetFile(uri)`. Hence, if my provider gets called for the `FileExists` method, it should be called for the `GetFile` method. What kind of code or context are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic actually used is if the file exists then IIS must be able to serve it directly and ASP.NET doesn't need to do anything more. If the file extension is .aspx, IIS will then pass it back to ASP.NET and GetFile will be called.

You could try having asp.net handle all .js files or something like that, but the easiest solution in this case is probably to add a route that matches the file url and calls a controller action that sends the file.